# Pycharm Makefile support does not initialize shell correctly

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, pycharm, virtualenv

So, this is new to me. I had some projects with similar Pycharm configurations working correctly, but I am trying to troubleshoot this issue in Kubuntu 22.04 (not sure if it's relevant).

Briefly:

- I am using pyenv + pyenv-virtualenv to initialize a Python virtual environment
- write a Makefile to execute some command
- Setup Pycharm with Makefile Languange plugin and create a run configuration
- Running the makefile configuration does not use the virtualenv

Details:

I create a virtualenv and automatically enable it when in the folder using `pyenv`

```bash
pyenv install 3.8.10
pyenv virtualenv 3.8.10 testenv
cd /some/project/dir/
echo "testenv" > .python-version
```

I then create a Pycharm project, configure Pycharm to use testenv and also install Pycharm Makefile Language

[image]

Install the requirements like `pip install -r requirements.txt`

```
#requirements.txt (example)
black==22.10.0
isort==5.10.1
```

The Makefile looks like this

```
.PHONY: format

format:
    isort .
    black .
```

When I run `make format` from the terminal. It works just fine.

When I run the following configuration, it acts like it is not using the virtualenvironment at all. I have tried several absolute and relative path configurations with no success.

[image]

Finally note that, running the make command which the configuration creates (the first line on the terminal window) from a terminal anywhere on my system works just fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know much about pycharm etc.  But, you do understand that the way `virtualenv` works is by modifying the current process's environment (`PATH` etc.)?  And the way that environments work is they are inherited by processes from their parent when they are started.  So if you have a terminal window and you have a pycharm running at the same time, they do not **SHARE** any environment.  Changes you make to one (your terminal) have no effect on the other (the pycharm program).

Comment: Similarly, if you set up pyenv in a terminal then start a pycharm from your desktop applications menu, that pyenv in your terminal has no effect on the pycharm because setting an environment in your terminal doesn't impact the environment of your desktop which started pycharm.  The only way to have pycharm see the pyenv is if you set it in a terminal, _then start pycharm from that terminal_ from the command line, while the pyenv is in effect.

Comment: Normally this is not how it's done.  Normally how it's done is that the pyenv is set _in the makefile recipe_ so that regardless of what the environment is when `make` is invoked, you get the pyenv environment you want.